# Verify all check boxes in a repeating table are checked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, designer-workflow, infopath-rules

I have created a very simple form in InfoPath. There is a part where I have added a repeating table. One column of the repeating table is a check box.
My requirement is to set a textbox field with a value of "Approved" on a button click if all the checkboxes are checked.
I have added a rule if the checkbox is checked then set value at the textbox to "Approved". but it fails. It not checking all the checkboxes. Simply checking one.

Please help me